# SQL Change in one table automatically change the other table

Tags: sql-server

I am new to Database and in SQL also. I have two tables t1 and t2. There is a "name" column in t1 and t2 tables. Here t1. name will be given by me, but I want that t2. name automatically change on the basis of t1. id=t2. id please help me by giving SQL query for it. Also tells me "is, stored procedures or triggers required for this?" If yes, then how I will use them? Thanks in advance..... :-)

Comment: You need to use a trigger to do this. Have you tried studying about triggers on books online?

Comment: no i don't i've just start the sql

Comment: Then BOL is a very good start point. Check it out

Comment: what do you mean by BOL???

Comment: books online https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Table2]
ON [dbo].[table1] AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN

   IF UPDATE (name)
   BEGIN

   INSERT INTO table2 (name)
   SELECT d.name FROM DELETED d


   END


END
```

I provided you an idea. Use it for updating the record. Here 'Deleted' table is the one where the data changed in table1 which can be used to store that previous data into other table that you want. I inserted the data, you update it now.

Sorry, I just saw it, you want the current data then use the 'INSERTED' table just like the 'DELETED'.